# Parse CSS in PHP

Tags: php, css, parsing

I need to parse a CSS file and change the path of an image in similar declarations to the following?

```
url("/images/...")
```

to  basically change anything in between `url("")`

---

I want to replace

```
url('images/img.jpg'), url("images/img.jpg")
```

and

```
url(images/img.jpg)
```

for `url(/newpath/images/img.jpg)`

I need to somehow get the current path so that I can append it to the new one

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe you can try looking at: [preg_replace()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Comment: at a guess, because you just provided a link... Nothing really useful as such

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
$line = "background-image: url(/images/image.png) no-repeat;";
//or $line = "background-image: url( /images/image.png ) no-repeat;";
echo preg_replace('/(?<=url\()[^\)]+(?=\))/x', '/newfolder/newimage.png', $line);
```

The regexp says:

- `[^\)]+` string of 1 caracter or more,  without `)`
- `(?<=url\()` before this string, there must be `url(`
- `(?=\))` after the string, there must be `)`
- `x` whitespace data characters in the pattern are totally ignored except when escaped or inside a character class ([more info](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)).

Comment: tip: use `x` modifier and put the explanation into the code. also you can use () for delimiters.

Comment: Added `x` modifier. I don't understand what u mean by `() for delimiters`. Feel free to edit my answer.

Comment: like this: http://codepad.org/cwV2Kphc. Makes it much easier to read this way IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions and `preg_replace`. Something like:

`url\(([^\)]+)\)`

Comment: THanks for the replies, what i actually wnat is capture anythign inside url() and use it for my replacement string. Sorry for not being clear the first time.

Comment: The code above does exactly just that. You need to place `url(\1)` as a replacement in `preg_match()`. `\1` contains the matched string inside the `url()`

Comment: preg_replace("/url\(\"([^\"]+\")\)", 'url("'.dirname($file).'/\1"), $cssContent);   how can i take into account cases like url("") or url('') or url()

Answer (score 0):

Or you could serve your css files as php scripts via .htaccess, like this:

```
<FilesMatch "\.css$">
    php_value default_mimetype "text/css"
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

And then in every css file you could defined your media path and use it wherever you want, like:

```css
<?php define('MEDIA_PATH', '../images/'); ?>
.class{background-image:url(<?php echo MEDIA_PATH;?>background.jpg)}
```